# KMP Algorithm, Pratt's Minimisation/optimization of Knuth's original DFA based algorithm

Tags: algorithms, automata, search-algorithms, strings

The Original Knuth's Algorithm is based on DFA and it depends on the `alphabet size`. And Then, Pratt optimised it to be independent of Alphabet Size.

But, All the textbooks directly give the final Pratt Algorithm.  Below is the code ( the code is not really needed to answer the question) which is more or less similar to original Knuth's Algorithm ( [full code](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/KMP.java.html)) , And it builds the DFA.

My Question is, How can we (idea behind) arrive at the final current version ( Pratt optimization) from below DFA version ?

Also, Is it called minimization of DFA, But DFA minimization can be applied to a specific alphabet(regular language), Here it applies to all alphabets ?

```
public KMP(char[] pattern, int R) { 
    // build DFA from pattern, R is the language length
    int M = pattern.length;
    dfa = new int[R][M]; 
    dfa[pattern[0]][0] = 1; 
    for (int X = 0, j = 1; j < M; j++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < R; c++) 
            dfa[c][j] = dfa[c][X];     // Copy mismatch cases. 
        dfa[pattern[j]][j] = j+1;      // Set match case. 
        X = dfa[pattern[j]][X];        // Update restart state. 
    } 
}
```